# Why is it sometimes impossible to edit Google Sheets formula line spacing?

Tags: google-sheets, formatting, google-sheets-formula, formula, string-formatting

[image]

I added spacing to the above formula, but as you can see there is a double line spacing near the bottom, and I'd like to add spacing at the top.  Yet no matter what I do, it maintains the same format.  I've even copied the formula to notepad, formatted it, deleted the formula from the cell, entered garbage into that cell to try to reset it, pasted the formula and BAAAM - it puts the spacing back where I don't want it.

Google Sheets has some PITA nuances to it, but this is really stupid.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Sheets remembers unnecessary stuff like all previous states of formatings. this, however, can be easily tricked. all you need to do is lowercase any function in a set and that qualifies as a "new" state.

in your case, you can set your desired format and then change `IFERROR` for `iFERROR` or `IfErRoR` or whatever you wish.

---

also it would work if you just change `Region` to `region`

---

or use alternative syntax logic like instead of:

```
IF(OR($B$13="Region", ISBLANK($C19)),,
```

you can write:

```
IF(($B$13="Region")+(ISBLANK($C19)),,
```

or:

```
IF(($B$13="Region")+($C19=""),,
```

which is all the same

---

also you can just wrap it into some other formula which won't anyhow affect the final result. it could be `QUERY`, `INDEX`, `ARRAYFORMULA`, ... just to add some more characters to it to force the new custom format

Comment: Oh man whoever programmed this into the software needs a smack upside the head.  Thanks for the solution again player0!  It works, but I discovered that I can NEVER have the same case for the formula that I originally had - which is a quandary for someone as pedantic as me!

Comment: @AaronIrvine yeah, I feel your pain. answer updated